# How can I split one big appsync into multiple smaller ones without changing FE?

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync

I have one big appsync graphql application running on AWS. FE is calling this Appsync as backend interface.

I also have a few small appsyncs running from other teams. I am thinking to combine them together but not sure how.

Each smaller appsync has its own schema. One way to do so is to combine all small appsync schemas into the big one appsync. And use datasource resolver to reference to other appsync endpoints. But in this way, do I have to keep duplicate the schemas? The big one schema includes everything and other small schema keep its own.

The resolvers in other small appsync are private so I can't make the big appsync to point direct to the other appsync's resolver.

Is there an easier way to do so?

Comment: I'm keen to hear any ideas around this